# How can I implement enums with dashes in GraphQl JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, graphql

GraphQL enums [can not use dashes](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1698) (and only allow underscore).

Moving on, I have enums with dashes.  They already exist, I'm not changing them; it would introduce bugs in places I can't easily check.

So, how can these be represented in GraphQL?

Is it possible to make a "fake" enum that meets the GraphQL criteria and then convert it to real values afterwards?

Or do I just have to make my own Scalar and forgo GraphIQL suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  Pretty easy; I'm surprised none of the threads or other questions I found said it:

```
const values: GraphQLEnumValueConfigMap = {};

["enum-1", "enum-2"].forEach((value) => {
  const gqlName = String(value).replace(/\-/g, "_");
  values[gqlName] = { value }
});

const gqlEnum = new GraphQLEnumType({"my_enum_name", values});
```

Each `GraphQLEnumValueConfig` in `GraphQLEnumValueConfigMap` can have a property `value: any` set to what their value should be.

Depending on what your enums are, you may want to change the logic on how the gqlName is generated.